# How to create custom toast message?

Tags: android, toast

I want to add custom UI components in my toast message. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can't make a `Toast` in the `XML` code. However, you can make a `button` AND a `Toast` in `Java` programmatically. So it is the same, but not in your `XML`code but in your `Java` code.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a custom button by extending `Button` class.

```
public class CustomButton extends Button {

public CustomButton (Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public CustomButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

public CustomButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }
}
```

Inside this class you could assign it an `OnClickListener` which shows a `Toast` with your message. And then in your `XML` file you could refer to it like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<your.package.name.CustomButton 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.statsviewlayout);
    Button buyButton = new Button(this);
    buyButton.setText(R.string.button_back);
    buyButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.addView(GT); // line 27
    layout.addView(buyButton);       
    setContentView(layout);      

buyButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is Toast!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: Remember, this is `Java` code, not `XML`, but it is a good solution, +1

Comment: I ment this part: `: Whenever I copy then paste the button code in the xml file`

Comment: @Neo its helpful for you.??